# Justifying the existence of an improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, improper-integrals

[function with 2 variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhHJy.png)

can someone please help me with this

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please don’t rely on images to state your question; see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34121.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon making the change $t \to t\sqrt(x)$ the integral becomes:
\begin{equation}
F(x) = \frac{\pi}{4} \frac{\ln(x)}{\sqrt(x)}+\frac{1}{\sqrt(x)}\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln(t)}{1+t^2}dt
\end{equation}
The last integral is found to be $0$ by the change $t \to \frac{1}{t}$.
So $F(x)$ exists and is defined for $x>0$ as:
\begin{equation}
F(x) = \frac{\pi}{4} \frac{\ln(x)}{\sqrt(x)}
\end{equation}